# Expand the submenu based on active URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar list which has submenus. Each list item has a link to a different page. I want the submenu to expand on 2 conditions:

1. When its parent link is active only its children should expand.
2. When any of the child of a particular list is active, 
   expand the submenu of a list based on active URL.

```css
.menu-sidebar .child-ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-sidebar">
  <li class="parent-li">
    <a href="A.html">A</a>
    <ul class="child-ul">
      <li><a href="../1.html">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="../2.html">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.html">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="../4.html">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="../5.html">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="../6.html">6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent-li">
    <a href="B.html">B</a>
    <ul class="child-ul">
      <li><a href="11.html">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="12.html">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="13.html">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="14.html">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="15.html">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="16.html">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="17.html">7</a></li>
      <li><a href="18.html">8</a></li>
      <li><a href="19.html">9</a></li>
      <li><a href="20.html">10</a></li>
      <li><a href="21.html">11</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent-li">
    <a href="C.html">C</a>
    <ul class="child-ul">
      <li><a href="21.html">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="22.html">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="23.html">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="24.html">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="25.html">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="26.html">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="27.html">7</a></li>
      <li><a href="28.html">8</a></li>
      <li><a href="29.html">9</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Image of menu and submenu -

[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? If so, please edit the question to include it. At the moment this is a 'write my code for me' request, and is likely to be downvoted and closed because of that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I really appreciate your patience and very good explanation on every post, keep it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a simple click function with jQuery?

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).children("ul").length) {
    //toggle the class of child
  }
});
```

This has been done a million times so you should be able to find the code to toggle the class